# Understanding holding a reference in function call return vs creating a copy

Tags: java

I have the below Java code:

```
public class A extends B {
    private final Msg msg;

    public A(Resource resource){
        super(resource);

        CFile file = resource.getLocalFile();
        this.msg = file.getMsg(TypeRefs.aMsg());
    }

    public Msg getMsg() {return msg;}
  }
```

Assuming that Resource class and respective methods exist.

Is there any problem at line `this.msg = file.getMsg(TypeRefs.aMsg());`?

I am holding a reference from the function call return, is this safe? Or could anyone help suggest what would be a safer way to code this? (I got a feedback that I should make a copy of the msg and not do what I'm currently doing, but I would like to understand more about the problem on this platform)

Comment: Without more context I'd say whoever gave you feedback is a C/C++ guy/gal who doesn't understand the Java memory model. Either that or the feedback was not related to memory safety like you seem to be implying.

Comment: Is `Msg` mutable or immutable? Is it a new instance or a shared instance? Is it a problem if the instance returned by `getMsg` is modified from the outside?

Comment: @knittl Msg is immutable

Answer (score 3):

The comments on the question have the crucial detail:

> Msg is immutable

In that case, the reference to the this instance can be passed around freely. The object cannot be changed, so why bother making an identical copy? Copies will use additional memory, without anything to gain.

The story would be different if the object was actually mutable. In that case, a *defensive copy* could avoid some accidental bugs (modifying the value and affecting all references).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For my understanding if this was mutable, what would be the correct way here to make the defensive copy? (sorry for the basics, new to java)

Comment: @Kat.S: create a new instance, set all fields of the new instance to the value of the old instance. If a field is a complex object, make a new defensive copy. Or provide a way for an instance to give you a copy of itself. Not all objects can be copied, because some information might not be accessible from the outside. In such a case, the object definition must be changed provide this feature (e.g. via a `createCopy()` method). There's no one size fits all answer.